# PyInstaller exe works only with -F option

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have a MyFile.py that i bundle in an exe with `PyInstaller 3.6`:

```
pyinstaller -y -F MyFile.py
```

MyFile.exe works fine but if i do:

```
pyinstaller -y MyFile.py
```

Then, the exe does not work anymore. It just crashes immediatly after the console window is open

I would prefer to generate the exe without the `one file` (-F) option as it is faster to launch, but i don't know why i have not the same behavior. Sorry for the lack of information but i don't know where to start searching.

Comment: Could you show your error trackback?

Comment: I actually have nothing to show. When i launch it, it ends immediatly, nothing happen except that the exe file is actually deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved my problem. Actually, I made a script that build the exe in a temporary directory and then move the requirement (such as the exe) in my project's directory. During that moving part, i rename the exe file so that it fit the project's version. But that is the rename that cause the probleme.

Indeed, when -F option is added, I rename the bundled exe so nothing change in the underlying config. But without -F option, the original exe name is part of the configuration file so it can't work anymore.

I should have tell you that at first. My bad.